# Merging bipartite graphs - coloring?

Tags: coloring, bipartite-graphs

I've been battling with this question for a few days now:
We have 5 graphs (G1, G2, G3, G4, G5), each of which is a bipartite graph.
V is divided into Ai, Bi (for each graph respectively).
Let G be the merged graph (merging all edges and removing duplicates).
What would be the maximal number of colors required to color it?

Each and every attempt I make at resolving this ends up being related to the size of V when the intuition dictates otherwise.

The more edges in each graph the closer G becomes to being K (a full graph).

Does the largest rank define the coloring?
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Well certainly 32 colors is enough, just remember the colors in each individual graph.  Moreover it's not too hard to construct five graphs which require 32 total colors:  Each one is a copy of $K_{16,16}$ where we label the vertices from 0 to 31 and the parts of $G_n$ are determined by the $n$th binary digit. Of course smaller graphs might need fewer colors.

Comment: Thanks but could you clarify why 32? If we remember each color from the individual graphs wouldn't we get 10? and how does this not correlate to the number of vertices

Comment: For example if we have just two graphs we are coloring black and white then the possible colors we have when we glue them are (black, black), (black, white), (white, black) and (white, white). So we have to "multiply" the colorings rather than adding them.